Is it bad practice to use ros2 parameters as variables?
I have a Pioneer 3DX-SH motorized robot base communicating with a ROS2 node I am currently coding, exchanging information about which speed to set the wheels to and what the current odometry estimate is. The robot is also equipped with an emergency stop button, to which the firmware reacts by decelerating the wheels and setting a flag (which can be read and written to by the ROS2 node through serial communication).
Is it bad practice to expose this flag as one of this node's parameters? It looks like parameters offer the abstractions fitting for the application: reading the current status of the emergency stop button and resetting the motors when possible, but it also feels like the reason parameters exist is more to change behaviour, reconfiguring the software.

Semantically, I think a service get_emergency_stop_status returning a status message is a more appropriate solution, as you are requesting the node to provide status info.
You could use a parameter for that as well, but in order to access the parameter, you would need to issue a service call anyway (get_parameters, see here).
But either way will work.
Edit:
An example: let's say you have a drive which has a PID controller, an enable/disable toggle and a physical E-stop button. Then I would implement:

Three parameters: for the P, I and D values,
A service set_enable which takes true/false to enable/disable,
Possibly also a service get_enable_status which returns true/false if the drive is enabled/disabled,
A service get_E-stop_status which returns whether the E-stop is pressed or not.

That being said, it is perfectly possible to implement this in a different way, e.g. with a subscriber to a topic /enable instead of a service set_enable. But:

Imo. this is less clean,
There's no direct way to provide feedback (e.g. let's say you try to enable but it fails since the E-stop is pressed. A service can provide a return value indicating success/failure whereas a subscription cannot).

Edit 2:
If your robot has several states (unconfigured/inactive/active/etc), then it might be relevant to have a look at lifecycle nodes.

But then I would also need another service or listening topic for setting the disabled_motors flag right?

I added an example to my answer.

The services you described for renaming the motors are also available when parameters are declared, are they not? The problem with doing the same thing with parameters instead of writing the services myself is a discussion of semantics then?

It's semantics, but also a matter of which functionality you require. E.g. consider an enable operation which can fail if the E-stop is pressed. This is the basic use case for a service. If you use a parameter instead, you will either need to check the boundary conditions before setting the enable parameter, or (better option) you will need to implement an on_set_parameters_callback to approve or reject the change.

It is not good practice, for what you mention.
I would publish the e-stop status as a topic, as you want to inform user and system all the time. Then a service for setting or resetting it.

Can you elaborate why it's not good practice?
